# AngularJS How to access elements inside directive before they get replaced

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I get the input element from within the directive before the template overwrites the contents?

html

```
<div xxx>
  <input a="1" />
</div>
```

js

```
app.directive('xxx', function(){
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<p></p>',
        replace: true, //if false, just leaves the parent div, still no input
        compile: function(element, attrs) {

            console.log(element);

            return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            }
        }
    };
});
```

i am on angular 1.0.x, I cannot pass in optional scope parameters with the '=?' syntax and i want to be able to override a portion of the default template of the directive in a very flexible way. instead of adding a scope variable or attribute everytime that I just plan on passing through the directive, I want to be able to supply the whole element to be used.

**edit**
the input must retain the scope of the directive, and not the parent.

**edit**
I am trying to include a partial template inside a directive that will overwrite a piece of the actual template. The piece I am including therefore needs to have access to the directive's scope and not the parent's.

**Update**
It seems if I do not provide a template or a template URL and instead replace the contents manually using the $templateCache I can have access to the inner elements. I want to let angular handle the template and the replacement though and just want to be able to access the contents in the directive naturally before they get replaced.

**Solution**
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HWELU5dRePrqCmcXm5xe?p=preview)

html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div editable="obj.email">
            <input validate-email="error message" ng-model="obj.email" name="contactEmail" type="text" />
        </div>
  </body>
```

js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {
    email: 'xxx'
  };
});

app.directive('editable', function($log){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-show="localScopeVar">{{value}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        scope: {
          value: '=editable'
        },
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.localScopeVar = true;
        }
    };
});


app.directive('validateEmail', function($log){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
          console.log(attrs['validateEmail']);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What you need to do with the input element?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do. but if you would like to keep the input element you should use the ng-transclude directive at the p element and set the option transclude:true in your directive code.

Comment: It should be `template: '<p ng-transclude></p>',` if you use `transclude: true`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [transclude](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/guide/directive) function (link is to 1.0.8 docs). You can see what's going on with:

```
app.directive('xxx', function($log){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        compile: function(element, attrs, transclude) {

            $log.info("every instance element:", element);

            return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

                $log.info("this instance element:", element);

                transclude(scope, function(clone){

                    $log.info("clone:", clone);

                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @dfsq and @Michael are correct, if you want to pass in the elements between the directive tags into your template, then you should use `ng-transclude` on the element you would like the elements to be place. The above will give to direct access to the transcluded elements.

Comment: if you add a template to this directive then it does not work. in that case it doesn't matter if transclude is true or false.

Comment: I added `template: "<strong>Testing</strong><div ng-transclude></div>"` to the directive in my answer and the `clone` in the transclude function still logs the `<input>`

Comment: OK yes I see that it does in fact log the content in the template has ng-transclude directive on something. +1 but the problem with this solution for me is that I need the input element to have the scope of the directive, not the parent.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to do. It sounds like you want to doubly bind a variable in an isolated scope without using '=' or declaring it as an attribute? Is that right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it's confusing too. I am trying to include a partial template inside a directive that will overwrite a piece of the actual template. The piece I am including therefore needs to have access to the directive's scope and not the parent's.

Comment: I got it working, using mostly your answer. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HWELU5dRePrqCmcXm5xe?p=preview)

Comment: Ok yeah, now I understand transclusion. You were completely correct.