# Accessible Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the Bootstrap Modal be accessible to screen readers. This means I need to add a `role="dialog"` or similar to the highest level div of the modal.
My problem is that I can't add anything to the correct level divs as they are generated.

This code adds the `role="dialog"` to the 2nd highest div of the modal.

```
<div class="modal-content" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Are you sure you want to clear all responses in this section?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ok()" role="button" aria-label="Confirm clearing of the entire section">Ok</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()" role="button" aria-label="Deny clearing of the entire section">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the role on the shown div, but that one and the parent are generated and I don't have control over them.

[image]

I am showing the modal via

```
$scope.clearSection = function () {
        var modal = $modal.open({
            controller: clearSectionController,
            templateUrl: 'Engine/Views/ClearSectionModal.html'
        });
        ...
}
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe we dealt with this by updating the $templateCache to override the template bootstrap provides (iirc template/modal/window.html) . I can check tomorrow

Comment: @swestner is right.  'windowTemplateUrl' gives the option of overriding the containing div.  This discussion - https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4878 is about an issue but it does given example of what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS How to access elements inside directive before they get replaced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240664/angularjs-how-to-access-elements-inside-directive-before-they-get-replaced)